I would like to make a Fancy Chapter like given template below
I would like to make a Fancy Chapter like given template below

% Here is what I tried
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries}{\Large\chaptername~\thechapter\endgraf%
    \tikz\draw[very thick,fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,-0.25);%
    \titlerule[1pt]}{-3ex}{\LARGE\filcenter}%
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\bfseries}{\Large\endgraf%
    \tikz\draw[very thick,fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,-0.25);%
    \titlerule[1pt]}{-3ex}{\LARGE\filcenter \thesection~}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Background}
\end{document} 



You must try something first.

What have you tried so far? Please show us a short compilable TeX code! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Feel free to adapt it to your taste.
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for mock text

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\LARGE}
  {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\formattitle[-\baselineskip]{\LARGE}{}}

\newcommand{\formattitle}[4][0pt]{%
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
    #2% fontsize
    \vspace{#1}
    \hrule
    \hrule height 3pt width 0.3\textwidth
    \vspace{0.2ex}
    \hspace{0.32\textwidth}%
    \parbox[t]{0.68\textwidth}{\raggedright#3#4}%
  }%
}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\Large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\formattitle{\Large}{\thesection~}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[display]
  {\Large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\formattitle{\Large}{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\section{Background}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\section{A long section title that needs being split across lines}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\section*{Unnumbered section}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{document} 



